# How to delete surrounding brackets?

Tags: balanced-parentheses, parentheses

I'd like to be able delete the innermost brackets around the current point.

What's a good way to do this?

While the evil-surround package can do this, it needs to take a bracket type as input, so can't remove the inner-most brackets (without some extra code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`up-list`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Motion.html#index-up_002dlist-3448) or [`backward-up-list`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Motion.html#index-backward_002dup_002dlist-3449) to move forward or backward to the first enclosing bracket, then `forward-list` or `backward-list` to locate the matching bracket. Delete the closing bracket then the opening bracket (in this order, because deleting the opening bracket moves the position of the closing bracket.

```el
(defun delete-enclosing-parentheses (&optional arg)
  "Delete the innermost enclosing parentheses around point.

With a prefix argument N, delete the Nth level of enclosing parentheses,
where 1 is the innermost level."
  (interactive "*p")
  (save-excursion
    (backward-up-list arg)
    (let ((beg (point)))
      (forward-list)
      (delete-backward-char 1)
      (goto-char beg)
      (delete-char 1))))
```

Comment: Thanks, this mostly works well - however the behavior is asymmetrical - when the cursor is over the end bracket, it matches the first. When over the first bracket, it doesn't match the last.

Comment: Added an answer which uses this method but works when the point is an opening brace too: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/54679/2418

Comment: @ideasman42 Emacs's idea of the cursor is that it's between characters, not on a character, although many terminal types show the cursor on a character. When the cursor is “on” the opening bracket, it's actually before the opening bracket, so it's outside. You can adopt a different convention, but it'll be inconsistent with how brackets work with some Emacs commands.

Comment: Good points, since I asked about "surrounding" bracket's, your answer is correct. Although I'll keep using my more verbose solution that handles the case when the point is over the bracket too.

Comment: You can also use `(delete-pair)` in place of the whole form that begins with the let-binding. I don't know exactly what the differences are, though. Mine, with `delete-pair`, used to go crazy when called from within strings. Using `(backward-up-list arg t t)` tamed it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer based on @gilles-so-stop-being-evil 's current answer which works when the point is on the opening bracket as well as the last bracket, it also error checks and prints useful status upon completion.

```el
(defun my-delete-surround-at-point--find-brackets (pos)
  "Return a pair of buffer positions for the opening & closing bracket positions.
Or nil when nothing is found."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char pos)
    (when
        (or
         ;; Check if we're on the opening brace.
         (when
             ;; Note that the following check for opening brace
             ;; can be skipped, however it can cause the entire buffer
             ;; to be scanned for an opening brace causing noticeable lag.
             (and
              ;; Opening brace.
              (eq (syntax-class (syntax-after pos)) 4)
              ;; Not escaped.
              (= (logand (skip-syntax-backward "/\\") 1) 0))
           (forward-char 1)
           (if (and (ignore-errors (backward-up-list 1) t) (eq (point) pos))
               t
             ;; Restore location and fall through to the next check.
             (goto-char pos)
             nil))
         ;; Check if we're on the closing or final brace.
         (ignore-errors (backward-up-list 1) t))

      ;; Upon success, return the pair as a list.
      (list (point)
            (progn
              (forward-list)
              (1- (point)))))))

(defun my-delete-surround-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((range (my-delete-surround-at-point--find-brackets (point))))
    (unless range
      (user-error "No surrounding brackets"))
    (pcase-let ((`(,beg ,end) range))
      ;; For user message.
      (let ((lines (count-lines beg end))
            (beg-char (char-after beg))
            (end-char (char-after end)))

        (save-excursion
          (goto-char end)
          (delete-char 1)
          (goto-char beg)
          (delete-char 1))
        (message
         "Delete surrounding \"%c%c\"%s" beg-char end-char
         (if (> lines 1)
             (format " across %d lines" lines)
           ""))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer I came up with, adding for completeness, however I'd rather not depend on evil-surround because it gives less control and is more likely to break.

```lisp
(defun delete-surround-at-point (arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (let
    (
      (best-range most-positive-fixnum)
      (best-inner nil)
      (best-outer nil)
      (chars (list ?\( ?\[ ?\{ ?\" ?\'))
      (char-found nil))
    (dolist (c chars)
      (let*
        (
          (overlay-inner (ignore-errors (evil-surround-inner-overlay c)))
          (overlay-outer
            (and
              overlay-inner
              (<= (overlay-start overlay-inner) (point))
              (>= (overlay-end overlay-inner) (point))
              (ignore-errors (evil-surround-outer-overlay c)))))
        (if (and overlay-inner overlay-outer)
          (let ((test-range (- (overlay-end overlay-inner) (overlay-start overlay-inner))))
            (when (< test-range best-range)
              (setq best-range test-range)
              (when best-inner
                (delete-overlay best-inner)
                (delete-overlay best-outer))
              (setq best-inner overlay-inner)
              (setq best-outer overlay-outer)
              (setq char-found c)))
          ;; Else delete either overlay if it exists.
          (when overlay-inner
            (delete-overlay overlay-inner))
          (when overlay-outer
            (delete-overlay overlay-outer)))))
    (unless (null char-found)
      (evil-surround-delete char-found best-outer best-inner))
    (when best-inner
      (delete-overlay best-inner)
      (delete-overlay best-outer))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Brackets can be detected using `forward-sexp` and `backward-sexp`, this examples uses these functions to implement context sensitive bracket removal.

```lisp
(defun find-surrounding-brackets (pt &optional strict)
  "Find surrounding braces.

Argument PT is the point which is checked for brackets.

When argument STRICT is non-nil, only use braces at PT,
otherwise surrounding brackets are searched for."
  (catch 'match
    (let
      (
        (re-begin "\\((\\|{\\|\\[\\)")
        (re-end "\\()\\|}\\|\\]\\)")
        (pt-begin nil)
        (pt-end nil))

      ;; First check if we're already on an ending bracket with a match,
      ;; handle this as a special case because there is no ambiguity in this instance.
      ;; Otherwise search for the previous bracket.
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char pt)
        (save-match-data
          (cond
            ((looking-at re-begin)
              (when (setq pt-end (ignore-errors (forward-sexp) (1- (point))))
                (setq pt-begin pt)
                (throw 'match (list pt-begin pt-end))))
            ((looking-at re-end)
              (forward-char 1)
              (when (setq pt-begin (ignore-errors (backward-sexp) (point)))
                (setq pt-end pt)
                (throw 'match (list pt-begin pt-end)))))))

      ;; Now loop over preview brackets
      ;; until we find a match which includes `pt'.
      (unless strict
        (let ((pt-iter (1+ pt)))
          (while
            (setq pt-begin
              (save-excursion
                (goto-char pt-iter)
                (save-match-data
                  (when (search-backward-regexp re-begin (point-min) t 1)
                    (match-beginning 0)))))

            (setq pt-end
              (save-excursion
                (goto-char pt-begin)
                (ignore-errors (forward-sexp) (1- (point)))))

            (when (and pt-end (< pt pt-end))
              (throw 'match (list pt-begin pt-end)))
            (setq pt-iter pt-begin)))))
    (throw 'match nil)))

(defun delete-surround-at-point (arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (let ((range (find-surrounding-brackets (point))))
    (unless range
      (user-error "No surrounding brackets"))
    (pcase-let ((`(,start ,end) range))
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char end)
        (delete-char 1)
        (goto-char start)
        (delete-char 1)))))
```

Comment: Why are you searching for bracket characters rather than use context-sensitive built-in functions like `backward-up-list`? Using the built-in functions would be simpler and would handle cases like `(foo -!- "(")` correctly.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this function, adding new answer based on this.